# transact-SQl query left joining two tables and get all data from tables

Tags: sql-server, left-join

Let say I have two tables like the example below

```
TableA
A_Id | A_Value | A_Number
1       AAA       111
2       BBB       222
3       CCC       333

TableB
B_Id | A_Id | B_Value | B_Number
1       1       XXX       999
2       2       YYY       888
3      NULL     ZZZ       777
```

As you can see , **A_Id** is primary key for **TableA** and Foreign Key for **TableB**.
The result I want is to join those two table, get all rows from TableA and intersect rows.

**Required Result**

```
A_Id | A_Value | A_Number | B_Id | B_Value | B_Number
1       AAA       111        1      XXX       999
2       BBB       222        2      YYY       888
0       AAA       111        0      ''         0  <= this row is missing
0       BBB       222        0      ''         0  <= this row is missing
0       CCC       333        0      ''         0
```

As you can see, the first two rows are intersected rows and the next three row are all rows from **TableA**.

I already tried with left out join

```
select A.*, B.* from FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
TableB B on A.A_Id = B.A_Id
```

but third and fourth rows are missing.
How can I get like this result ?
**Note:** you can ignore the null/zero values since I already used ISNULL.

Comment: In your Required Result, for the last 3 rows, you are showing the A_Id as 0, instead of 1, 2 and 3. Is that intended, or would you like it to actually show the real A_Id values?

Comment: @tgolisch , yes , I want to show as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "Example Result" (above), it seems like you want something different (not a LEFT JOIN). It looks like you need matching records from TableA and TableB, and once-again everything from TableA. You can do that by using a UNION statement.  Like this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.B_Id, B.B_Value, B.B_Number 
FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B on A.A_Id = B.A_Id
UNION
SELECT *, 0 AS B_id, '' AS B_Value, 0 AS B_Number 
FROM TableA
```